# ICS FTP - function to check if file exists on the ftp server

Tags: delphi, ftp, internet-component-suite

Does someone know how can I check if a file exists on a ftp server using Over byte ICS FTP?
Do I have to list all files and then parse the result or there is another way to do this? 
Thank you.

I use to code below in Indy.It works. But in my project I want to use icsftp. How can I change this for ics ftp?

```
Function exista_fisier_pe_ftp_nonvizual(nume_fisier_cautat,ftp_host,ftp_port,ftp_username,ftp_password,ftp_directory:string;memo_loguri:Tmemo) :Boolean;
var l:TStringList;
    indyftp:Tidftp;
    Freq, StartCount, StopCount: Int64;
    TimingSeconds: real;

begin

dateseparator:='-';


{verific daca serverul ftp este ONLINE}
if not IS_FTP_ONLINE(ftp_username,ftp_password,ftp_host) then showmessage(datetimetostr(now)+' - serverul "'+ftp_host+'" este OFFLINE sau datele de conectare sunt incorecte!') else

begin

memo_loguri.Lines.Add(#13#10+'=====> START CAUTARE FISIER PE SERVER FTP <====='+#13#10);

{ START VERIFICARE VITEZA DE EXECUTIE }
QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(StartCount);



indyftp:=Tidftp.create(nil);
l:=tstringlist.create;

indyftp.Host:=ftp_host;
indyftp.Port:=strtoint(ftp_port);
indyftp.username:=ftp_username;
indyftp.password:=ftp_password;
indyftp.Passive:=true;
indyftp.Connect;

if indyftp.connected then
 begin
memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - conectat cu succes la "'+indyftp.Host+'" portul '+inttostr(indyftp.Port));
memo_loguri.Lines.add(datetimetostr(now)+' - detectare sistem de operare server ftp: "'+indyftp.SystemDesc+'"');

indyftp.ChangeDir(ftp_directory);

memo_loguri.Lines.add(datetimetostr(now)+' - accesez directorul "'+ftp_directory+'"');

 try
{listez toate fisierele de pe ftp}
indyftp.List(l, '', false);

if l.IndexOf(nume_fisier_cautat) > -1 then
begin
result:=true;
memo_loguri.Lines.add(datetimetostr(now)+' - fisierul "'+nume_fisier_cautat+'" exista pe serverul ftp in directorul "'+indyftp.RetrieveCurrentDir+'" ,are dimensiunea de '+ FormatByteSize(indyFTP.Size(nume_fisier_cautat))+' si a fost incarcat pe server la data ' +datetostr(indyFTP.FileDate(nume_fisier_cautat)));
end
else
begin
result:=false;
memo_loguri.Lines.add(datetimetostr(now)+' - fisierul "'+nume_fisier_cautat+'" nu exista pe serverul ftp');
end;

finally
  l.free;
end;
  indyftp.free;


{ STOP VERIFICARE VITEZA DE EXECUTIE }
QueryPerformanceCounter(StopCount);
TimingSeconds := (StopCount - StartCount) / Freq;
{ Display timing: ... }
memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now) + ' - comanda executata in: ' + formatfloat('0.00',TimingSeconds) + ' sec.'+#13#10);
memo_loguri.Lines.Add('=====> STOP CAUTARE FISIER PE SERVER FTP <====='+#13#10);

end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: is there a function to issue text commands?  there are at least two commands for that in FTP protocol

Comment: that say, there is a situation, when you can download a file and it exists, but listing would show nothing, so perhaps the most reliable check would be an attempt to download 10-20 bytes from the file

Comment: try functions `Size` / `FileSize` - http://www.mestdagh.biz/ics/help/

Comment: @Arioch'The: what situation would allow a non-listed file to be downloadable?

Comment: So I guess that I have to try downloading the file. If I receive an error than the result of the function is that the file does not exist. Else it exists. If ftp server return code is 200 the file exists else it doesn't?

Comment: @user2858981 why would it matter for your program what error it was exactly? If your program would know the error is this or that - what difference does it make? Would your program be able to fix some errors on server side but not others? I don't think so. I think, for the program it only matters if you can or can not download the file. The exact code and text of error (if any) you report to the user, and he talks with FTP admin and they resolve it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau simple: you do not have listing rights on the directory containing that file. Can you list EMBA FTP with Delphi ISO? Then I suspect MDTM and SIZE commands would still work, but LIST and NLST would not. So, if you know the final exact file URL (for example from EDN WWW cabinet, from e-mail, from forum), then you can `CD` to that directory, even without looking into it, and then you can issue `GET` or `PUT` command over that file, no matter that you can not "see" it. And file-specific `MDTM`/`SIZE` would probably work too (maybe not, dunno).

Comment: But if you do not know a priori the exact path and name, then you can not just `LIST` the files in the folder and point your finger "this one"

Comment: @Arioch'The: you are taking about HTTP. An HTTP server is not going to let you browse the contents of a folder (unless the folder is specifically configured for browsing). FTP, on the other hand, is designed for file management, you will always have listing rights. If you don't have rights to see a folder, you don't have rights to access its files, either. Most FTP servers (particular Unix-based) simply shell out to the OS to get the `LIST` data and pipe the output back to the client (there are dozens/hundreds of `LIST` formats used online, `MLSD`/`MLST` were introduced to standardize that).

Comment: @Arioch'The: the FTP protocol is *designed* to let a client "*just `LIST` the files in the folder and point your finger "this one"*". That is what **every** GUI-based FTP client does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau my example `you do not have listing rights on the directory containing that file` has NOTHING to do with clients. A client may send any commands it wants, but if the server says "i would not execute your commands, you have no rights for them" then so be it. Try to list all ISO's on EMBA FTP and see

Comment: @RemyLebeau u r welcome - ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/download/radstudio/10/

Comment: `If you don't have rights to see a folder, you don't have rights to access its files, either.` - nonsense. Also ambiguity - what do you even mean by "see a folder"? `Most FTP servers (particular Unix-based) simply shell out to the OS` - now what would happen if the user does not have EXECUTION grant onto the directory, that very `+X` in `chmod` terms ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: It is important for me to get the error because if the file already exists on the server i want to change the local file name from "file.txt" to "file_01.txt"and the upload it. I don't want to overwrite the file nor delete it.This is why I wanted to check if it exists or not on the server.

Comment: Then my best suggestion would be as I said above to try to query file size